# Why elements is disappeared when to use sort()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I found something on python.

This is coding that I've done.

```
>>>list = [ x for x in input("input your elements composed with only numbers:").split()]
>>>list = list.sort()      # in this point, all of values is disappeared..
```

Can you tell me, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.sort()` returns `None` and not a sorted list, you need to use `sorted(list)`...

Comment: Right.  It's doing the equivalent of sorting the list and then replacing it with None.